# Where is the connect tab within eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Where is the "connect tab" in eclipse ?

Its referenced in below text (ive circled the text in red), but I don't know where it is ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've created the debug launch configuration (and selected it), the Connect tab is the first one in that dialog window. Note that in recent versions of Eclipse, the menu labels are different. For example **Run > Debug configurations**... instad of **Run > Debug**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a screenshot:

[image]